How to create an outlook calendar event without registering an app on azure
I want to create a program that creates a calendar event on Outlook that contains a teams meeting link and invites other people to it. From the Microsoft Graph API documentation, it seems that I have to register an app to get the app ID to create an authentication token to be able to use the APIs.
I tried registering a new app on Azure, but I don't have permissions to register an app in my organization, is there a way around this? Or is there another way to create calendar events?

If the desktop version of Outlook is installed and has access to mailbox in question, you can use the Outlook Object Model.
